How to determine the type of distribution of random variable in that problem?
In average, one iPhone out of $k$ will break during the warranty period. Considering that one customer has only one iPhone, what is the probability that over $m$ customers out of $n$ will have their iPhone broken during the warranty period?
My main question about this problem is:

How do I determine the type of distribution of a random variable in such problem?

If that would be clear, I would know on to calculate the mean, the sigma, the distribution, and use that data in order to solve the problem. The exact way used to do it depends on the type of distribution.

If you are looking for the distribution of the random variable $X$ which models the number of broken Iphones among $n$ orders, then the multinomial distribution is what you are looking for.

@Daan: is the assumption that this is a multinomial distribution based on that 'every iPhone has equal probability to be broken during the warranty period'? It seems the basis to use binomial distribution.

Are you concerned only on the number of phones "broken" or also which of the customers' phones they are ? Pl. give this clarification.

I don't know if there is a generalised way of finding the type of distributions of a random variable, It will be different according to every problem that you come across and for this problem;
Let $X$ a random variable such that,
$$X= \text{number of iPhones broken out of} \ n  $$
then the distribution of $X$ would be $X \sim \text{Bin}(n,\frac{1}{k})$,
where $p=\frac{1}{k}$ is the probability that an iPhone breaks during the warranty period.
